# Network connection error after suspend Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, suspend, 14.04

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 and a DSL connection for internet. However, whenever I suspend and resume my session, I'm no longer able to connect to the internet. Could someone help me fix this?

Comment: Same with me. After stand-by network connections won't work. Tried to reactivate the connection via "cable connections" - no effect. Tried to re-sign-in into desktop - no effect. Only complete restart helps to establish connectivity. Kernel 3.13.0.24-generic Thanks for hints!

Comment: You might like to see if `nmcli nm sleep false` works better, as per: [Wireless networking not working after resume in Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/452826/wireless-networking-not-working-after-resume-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 20):

Robbin's answer fixes it for me.  To have this run every time the system wakes create a script with this content...

```sh
#!/bin/sh

case "${1}" in
    resume|thaw)
        service network-manager restart;;
esac
```

and put the script in `/etc/pm/sleep.d` and make it executable.  (The script is a slight variation of the one on [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452826/wireless-networking-not-working-after-resume-in-ubuntu-14-04))

Comment: In my tests it was definitely more reliable than the workaround with "nmcli nm sleep false". Thank you.

Comment: Why do we have to restart the network manager every time? Is this a bug in Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: @Phani: it might be https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1299282 or https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1289884.

Comment: I had forgotten about this thread. Will check the solution and update!

Comment: This works ```sudo service network-manager restart```

Answer (score 15):

I have been successful in bringing up the network by restarting networkmanager 100% of the times.

in a terminal:

```
$ sudo restart network-manager
```

Have not have time to check in to the issue more closely.

Answer (score 2):

I just turn off my wifi using the keyboard combination Fn + F2 and then turn it back on the same way (may be different for your computer). This restores my connection. Give it a try and see if that helps.

Comment: Yeah, this works for me too. Hardly an idea solution though, right? I find I can also right click on Network Manager to disable, then re-enable WIFI. Pretty tedious, but it does the job.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to recover the wifi after suspend by disabling the requirement for a password after suspend. This can be accomplished by unchecking the box in "Settings/Brightness&Lock"

Answer (score -6):

On a desktop running kubuntu 14.04 without wireless but having one nic with two vlans, static configuration in `/etc/network/interfaces`, none of all your suggestions helped.
This did the trick, no undesired sideeffects:

```
aptitude purge network-manager
```

and accepting the removal of plasma-nm;
now it works like a charm;
`apt-get purge` ... should do the same

Comment: And how do you want to control your network connections without NM? A **reinstallation** of network-manager may be helpful...

Comment: This is a well working solution for maybe a special situation, a desktop with a static net config; it may not be the best one for say a laptop with roaming, dhcp and wireless. What do you mean by "control your network connections"? I just want to control my servers and the office from this admin box.

Comment: @maumau: NetworkManager is the default system service in Ubuntu that manages and controls network connections. If you remove it, you'll have to take care of that yourself, which is a bad idea expect for very experienced users with complicated setups.