# Network-manager fails to enable network everytime after suspension, What can I do?

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager, suspend, 14.04

I have done the upgrade to 14.04LTS, after that, everytime I suspend my computer, when I turn it on, the network-manager fails to "enable" the network, and I always have to do:

```
sudo restart network-manager
```

It might be something mis-configured.. Can anyone solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: same here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/450688/network-connection-error-after-suspend-ubuntu-14-04/452166#452166

Comment: if coming out of suspension is a specific runlevel, then you could write a upstart job that would run that for you every time you come out of suspension.