# Wireless networking not working after resume in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, networking, suspend, 14.04, atheros

[Update]:
The same problem exists in Kubuntu and is solved in the same manner.
[Solved]:
By applying the following command `nmcli nm` I got the following:

Before suspend

```
RUNNING         STATE           WIFI-HARDWARE   WIFI       WWAN-HARDWARE   WWAN      
running         connected       enabled         enabled    enabled         enabled
```

as can you see the state is connected and the rest are enabled and running

After suspend

```
RUNNING         STATE           WIFI-HARDWARE   WIFI       WWAN-HARDWARE   WWAN      
running         asleep          enabled         enabled    enabled         disabled
```

as can you see the state is asleep meaning our dear network manager is still napping, so to solve use the fallowing command line:
`sudo nmcli nm sleep false`
this tells the network manager to wake the hell up.
to make this permenant :
create a script in `/etc/pm/sleep.d` containg the following (and don't forget to mark the script as executable):

```
#!/bin/sh

case "${1}" in
        resume|thaw)
        nmcli nm sleep false
                ;;
esac
```

Thanks to [this](http://patrick.vande-walle.eu/software/kubuntu/ubuntu-13-10-no-network-after-resuming-from-hibernation/)

The original problem:

I just downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 and installed on  my laptop: ASUS X61SL with Intel P8400 Core2Duo x64 processor.
When I close the lid, the system is suspended, but when I open the lid again and resume, the wireless networking is not activited (networking as a whole is disabled), and when I select "Enable Networking" nothing happens.
This is the information about my wireless adapter:

```
$ lspci | grep -i wireless
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
```

This problem wasn't present in Ubuntu 13.04, Linux Mint Debian Edition or Debian 7 wheezy (GNOME or KDE).

Edit: few test with the following results :
The problem effects my wireless and wired networking.
Note: I need to add the `pci=nomsi` line to grub in order to boot.
When logging out manually then suspend then resume then log in every thing works just fine.
When suspending directly while logged in the problem happens.
Locking and suspending causes the same problem as suspending directly.
Also this problem appearnlty affects log out function: if you chose log out from the user menu in unity panel then you wan't log out, but if you use the command line `gnome-session-quit --logout` then you can log out.
Now with `lshw -C network` output:
Normal (fully functional networking):

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 191 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
       vendor: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS]
       physical id: 4
       bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:24:8c:1e:f8:53
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sis190 driverversion=1.4 duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:19 memory:fddfcc00-fddfcc7f ioport:cc00(size=128)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 00:15:af:e2:13:db
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.13.0-24-generic firmware=N/A ip=6.6.6.8 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:16 memory:fdff0000-fdffffff
```

After resume ("/etc/pm/config.d" does not contains "unload_modules"):

```
 *-network DISABLED      
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 191 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
       vendor: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS]
       physical id: 4
       bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:24:8c:1e:f8:53
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sis190 driverversion=1.4 duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:19 memory:fddfcc00-fddfcc7f ioport:cc00(size=128)
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 00:15:af:e2:13:db
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.13.0-24-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:16 memory:fdff0000-fdffffff
```

When I added the file unload_modules to directory  "/etc/pm/config.d" as suggested by [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/fix-wireless-or-wired-network-not.html), after logging out, suspend ,resume then log in the networking works but I cannot connect to my wireless network.
Again the result of `lshw -C network`
After resume ( "/etc/pm/config.d" contains "unload_modules"):

```
 *-network DISABLED      
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 191 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
       vendor: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS]
       physical id: 4
       bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:24:8c:1e:f8:53
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sis190 driverversion=1.4 duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:19 memory:fddfcc00-fddfcc7f ioport:cc00(size=128)
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 00:15:af:e2:13:db
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.13.0-24-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:16 memory:fdff0000-fdffffff
```

The contents of 'unload_modules" where:

```
SUSPEND_MODULES="$SUSPEND_MODULES ath9k"
SUSPEND_MODULES="$SUSPEND_MODULES sis190"
```

Where 'ath9k' is my wireless module and 'sis190' is my Ethernet module.

Comment: I have disconnected instead of asleep in my status, how can I solve the problem with that? Thx

Comment: Just Suspend the system and then resume back in. This surprisingly solves the wifi issue! Worked for me [ubuntu 14.04 LTS x64 on Asus laptop]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems with networking after suspend](http://askubuntu.com/questions/361991/problems-with-networking-after-suspend)

Comment: If you solve your own problem, you should post an answer, not include the answer in your question.

Comment: @Duncan sorry about that :)

Comment: Still no official fix to this issue? As per reading the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1286552) no. But this is highly surprising as it seems to affect quite many people ...

Comment: On my old laptop Asus X61SL, the problem was present. On my new laptop Dell Inspiron 15R the problem is NOT present. Apparently it has to do with the hardware.

Comment: I have to also connect to the proxy manually every time. duh. Restarting the router (if possible) helps by the way.

Comment: The command `nmcli nm` complains: `Object 'nm' is unknown`

Comment: Same here, `Object 'nm' is unknown`. @Alireza did you find solution?

Comment: @umpirsky try `nmcli general status`

Comment: @Roman `$ nmcli general status
STATE      CONNECTIVITY  WIFI-HW  WIFI     WWAN-HW  WWAN    
connected  full          enabled  enabled  enabled  enabled`

Comment: @umpirsky yeah, I have similar results. I think this means that your wifi's dysfunction reason is different from the one OP had and the solution above won't help. In my case, restarting network manager (`sudo service network-manager restart
`) have helped, so I would recommend you to try that. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Yes, that one helps, I find it in answers below. Thanks.

Comment: I get this problem from time to time, but I don't have a connection to solve it when it happens so I reboot. Network should be so basic, I hope this is automated/solved in later versions of Ubuntu, as it really sucks.

Comment: Works for me on Kubuntu 16.04.1

Answer (score 27):

The above answers did not work for me on 14.10. After a bit of trial-and-error, I ended up with this,

```
#!/bin/sh

case "${1}" in
  resume|thaw)
    nmcli r wifi off && nmcli r wifi on ;;
esac
```

Put this in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_resume_wifi`
Make it executable `sudo chmod 755 /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_resume_wifi`
and the problem should be fixed immediately.

Comment: this resolved it for me on 15.04

Comment: Why not "off" before going to sleep?

Comment: What is the 'r' for? I get "Error: Object 'r' is unknown." This seems to work for me: "nmcli nm wifi on;" (ubuntu 14.04 - dell precision laptop)

Comment: Worked for me 16.04

Comment: @FizxMike The `r` specifies object 'radio' in my version of `nmcli` (Ubuntu 16.04). When I type `nmcli r --help`, I see the available targets of a command are `COMMAND := { all | wifi | wwan }` and the available commands are `[ on | off]`. I surmise that previous to Ubuntu 14.10, it was not possible to target individual objects that are controlled by NetworkManager.

Comment: Much cleaner working solution is '''sudo service network-manager restart'''

Answer (score 21):

I got a solution but it is just for restarting your network manager.

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

It is not the permanent solution.

Comment: This solution is the only one that worked for me on 15.10 with Intel Wireless 7260

Comment: This solution is also worked on 14.04 LTS and 14.10

Comment: Worked. @hmjha Maybe we can write a script in `/etc/pm/sleep.d` that checks if wifi works and restarts `network-manager` if not?

Comment: @umpirsky yes we can do from that method also. Thanks

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 16.10. However, apparently /etc/pm/sleep.d is no longer used. I put it instead in /lib/systemd/system-sleep, as:

#!/bin/sh

case $1 in
  post)
    service network-manager restart
    ;;
esac

Answer (score 4):

The script that finally worked for me:

```
$ cat /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_resume_wifi 
#!/bin/sh

case "${1}" in
  resume|thaw) nmcli nm sleep false ;;
esac

$ ll /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_resume_wifi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 70 mars  31 09:09 /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_resume_wifi
```

The other answer has typos (they can be fixed I know), but never worked for me anyway.

Comment: Can I somehow test this without making it permanent? What do the commands do?

Comment: Tokam, see my comment above on Owais' post about "nmcli nm wifi on" working in the script first. Basically, by placing a script in the sleep.d directory, it will be executed at resume time and get passed 'resume' or 'thaw'. The script checks for either arguments being passed to the script and executes the nmcli command (Network Manager Command Line Interface). The specific command I mentioned is equivalent to clicking on network manager in the status bar and checking "Enable WiFi". For verification, enter "nmcli nm help" in terminal. Also, you need to make sure the script it's executable.

Comment: This works for me on mint mate 18, which is based on ubuntu 16.04.1.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04 on Dell Precision laptop.

In a terminal enter:

```
sudo nano /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_resume_wifi
```

Then paste in (ctrl+v):

```
#!/bin/sh
case "${1}" in
resume|thaw)
    nmcli nm wifi on
    ;;
esac
```

Then make the script executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_resume_wifi
```

Test out suspend and wake to see wifi on!!

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried to make another script like this one enter in kate:

```
#/bin/sh

    case ![1] in
        ./bin/sh
        network="true"
        nmcli nm -c sleep=false -network
    endasc
```

and save it as jsin7 file in /etc/network, and call it network.d and this might work fine.

Comment: I think the syntax has recently changed, I isssued `nmcli nm sleep false` followed by `nm wifi on` to get it running. +1 for the tip!

Comment: The command `sudo nmcli nm sleep false` does work for me, so I'm not stuck. But the `/etc/network/network.d` script doesn't auto-resume. If I try to execute it, I get `Syntax error: newline unexpected (expecting ")")`. Could you be more specific on the 1. Why it doesn't work? 2. What is supposed to do the script (so we can fix it individually)? 3. Why `network.d`? Thanks!

Comment: What is this supposed to do? What is `![$]`? Why `./bin/sh`? You're in `/etc/network`, there will be no `./bin/sh` there. What's a `jsin7` file? Case statements end with `esac`, not `easc`. They also need a variable and a condition.