# No Wifi/Internet after Suspend

Tags: 12.04, wireless, internet

I have literally tried everything on the Internet but nothing helped me. The wifi gets hard blocked after suspend. Even *Rfkill* command won't work. Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

"Hard Blocked" refers to your "fn" keys on your laptop. Press "fn" along with the wifi button to toggle wifi on and off. Rfkill cannot override this switch. Don't feel bad if this is the problem I did the same thing the first time this happened to me.

Comment: I've even tried that. It should have come on after 'fn' plus 'f12' but it didn't :/

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
#!/bin/sh

case "${1}" in
  resume|thaw)
    nmcli r wifi off && nmcli r wifi on;
esac
```

Put this in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_resume_wifi` and the problem should be fixed immediately.

Copied my own answer from [Wireless networking not working after resume in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452826/wireless-networking-not-working-after-resume-in-ubuntu-14-04/608897#608897)

Answer (score 0):

I have this same kind of behavior, wifi gets back to work with

> sudo service network-manager restart

hope it helps.