# Wifi not resuming after suspend

Tags: 14.04, wireless, broadcom, b43

Wifi worked fine on my dell inspiron e1505 with broadcom 4311 wifi.

Since upgrading to 14.04, wifi does not work after resuming from (close-the-lid) suspend.  If I then manually put it in suspend again with the keyboard, wifi works on resume ~95% of the time.

output from lspci and lshw follows.

lspci | grep -i network
   0b:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN (rev 01)

> lshw
>         *-network
>             description: Network controller
>             product: BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN
>
> ```
>       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
>       physical id: 0
>       bus info: pci@0000:0b:00.0
>       version: 01
>       width: 32 bits
>       clock: 33MHz
>       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
>       configuration: driver=b43-pci-bridge latency=0
>       resources: irq:16 memory:efdfc000-efdfffff
>  *-network
>       description: Ethernet interface
>       product: BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX
>       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
>       physical id: 0
>       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
>       logical name: eth0
>       version: 02
>       serial: 00:15:c5:a5:9d:b0
>       size: 10Mbit/s
>       capacity: 100Mbit/s
>       width: 32 bits
>       clock: 33MHz
>                                                   capabilities: pm bus_master >cap_list ethernet physical mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
>   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=b44 driverversion=2.0 >duplex=half latency=64 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
>   resources: irq:17 memory:ef9fe000-ef9fffff
> ```
>
> *-network
>         description: Wireless interface
>         physical id: 2
>         logical name: wlan1
>         serial: 00:16:cf:17:a4:4f
>         capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
>         configuration: broadcast=yes driver=b43 driverversion=3.13.0-35-generic >firmware=666.2 ip=192.168.1.103 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg>

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of trial-and-error, I ended up with this,

```
#!/bin/sh

case "${1}" in
  resume|thaw)
    nmcli r wifi off && nmcli r wifi on;
esac
```

Put this in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_resume_wifi` and the problem should be fixed immediately.

Copied my own answer from [Wireless networking not working after resume in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452826/wireless-networking-not-working-after-resume-in-ubuntu-14-04/608897#608897)

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem with an HP dv9000 with a BCM4311 in it.

Tried this in the terminal and it worked after sleep to bring the interface back up:

```
nmcli nm sleep false
```

So I just adapted the solution above to use this new string instead of the one that turns it off/on again.  So it looks like this and it works great:

```
#!/bin/sh

case "${1}" in
  resume|thaw)
    nmcli nm sleep false;
esac
```

Be sure to make it executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_resume_wifi
```