# Wifi stops working after suspend, 14.04.2

Tags: wireless, suspend

EDIT: New info - the problem of Wifi not working after suspend is fixed by downgrading to kernel 3.2 - unfortunately the downgrade causes other problems like my mouse cursor freezing and lagging, and ubuntu keeps giving error messages. Only the downgrade solves the problem, an upgrade to kernel 4.0.4 changes nothing.

When I turn on my computer after it has been completely shut down, the wifi connection works fine. However, if I suspend then resume, I cannot detect any networks. How do I get it to work properly? I am a Linux newbie and do not have much experience fixing these kinds of issues.

I am using: Ubuntu 14.04.2. In case it matters, it is set up as a dual-boot with Windows 7.

This issue is not new for me, I have experienced it a while back before 14.04.2. This is the primary reason I do not use Linux - it is inconvenient and wastes time to restart my computer all the time just to use the Internet, so I would greatly appreciate a solution that actually works. I've looked up solutions but nothing works for me (they usually involved making or editing some weird config file that does nothing).

My wireless card is a TP Link TL-WN951N. It is *supposedly* supported by Linux from what I can find online.

Also, in case it matters, this is the result of typing

```
lspci -v | grep -A 10 -i "Network Controller"
```

into the terminal.

```
Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR5416 Wireless Network Adapter [AR5008 802.11(a)bgn] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Qualcomm Atheros Device 3071
Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 168, IRQ 19
Memory at fbef0000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: ath9k
```

Comment: So after much messing around and wondering what to do,  I decided to downgrade to kernel 3.2 and the problem is fixed... but now I have a bunch of other problems: ubuntu 14.04 giving me error messages, and my mouse cursor freezes/lags....
perhaps a lot of 14.04 relies on the newer kernel? I might just remove ubuntu 14.04 and install 12.04

Anyways, at least I've found out that the culprit is the kernel

Comment: updates: I tried installing a new kernel, 4.0.4, to see if the problem was fixed for a _newer_ kernel, but it was not. So much for the Linux kernel being "up"dated. I guess I'm stuck with 3.2

Comment: I have 14.05 and my WiFi just reconnects when it comes out of suspend, all by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart `network-manager`

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: I tried it but it didn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

I have the same wifi card (TP Link TL-WN951N) using Kubuntu 14.04. After waking up my computer, the NetworkManager shows the wifi being connected, but it's not. If I disable and then enable wireless network using the NetworkManager, the wifi connects and works well. To make it automatic, I created a script `/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_resume_wifi` that does the same when a computer wakes up (inspired by [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452826/wireless-networking-not-working-after-resume-in-ubuntu-14-04)):

```
#!/bin/sh

case "${1}" in
  resume|thaw)
    nmcli nm wifi off && nmcli nm wifi on;
esac
```

It's necessary to make the script executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_resume_wifi
```