# WiFi not working after suspend (14.04)

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, suspend

My WiFi did not turn on after suspending. So I followed the steps found here [Wireless networking not working after resume in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452826/wireless-networking-not-working-after-resume-in-ubuntu-14-04) to fix it. Now it does turn on, but only every other time. Any advice on how to fix that issue? The WiFi adapter is an Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260.

Comment: did you tried `sudo service network-manager restart`

Comment: No I hadn't, it does fix the issue but it's only a one time fix however.

Comment: Which answer(s) to the linked question did you try? There are many and it's difficult to suggest something without that knowledge.

Comment: I made the script found in the first post. @DavidFoerster

Comment: @LievenLagast: [This one](/a/608897/175814)? Did you try any of the other answers? There are some other, often subtly different, suggested solutions.

Comment: Yes that's the one. and yes the same issue does persist across all solutions I tried.

Comment: What's the expected behaviour you are looking for ? @LievenLagast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what seems to happen is that this script:

```
#!/bin/sh 
case "${1}" in
    resume|thaw)
    nmcli nm sleep false
            ;;
esac
```

Sometimes executes directly upon logging in and sometimes only after half a minute after logging in again. So I'll just leave it at that and consider the issue fixed for the time being. If there is a way to make the script execute faster I'll try to find it and post it here.

Comment: Which script? I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about what you did. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)