# Wifi doesnt work after wake from suspend

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, suspend

After waking from suspend, my wifi doesn't work. I'm using a USB wifi adapter.

In the Network Manager indicator dropdown, "Enable networking" is checked, "enable Wi-Fi" isn't appearing at all.

When I run `nmcli nm`, the `STATE` is `disconnected`, rather than `asleep` as in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452826/wireless-networking-not-working-after-resume-in-ubuntu-14-04).

When I run ifconfig, wlan1 doesn't appear at all.

My current solution is to run `sudo killall NetworkManager` each time I wake my computer. This does reinstate `wlan1`, and the internet works again.

What's the way forward here? Do I need a new driver? Change a NetworkManager permission? Write a script to killall NetworkManager every wake?

Answer (score 0):

Since you know what fixes it via the command line, I'd just place that in a script that automatically runs during wake with the problem solved in a minute or so: [how to execute a command after resume from suspend?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92218/how-to-execute-a-command-after-resume-from-suspend)