# Wifi not working after resume

Tags: networking, wireless

I have problem my wifi doesnt work after resume.

I already tried lot of solution over google.

What currently I have:

**cat /etc/pm/sleep.d/wakenet.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in
thaw|resume)
nmcli nm sleep false
pkill -f wpa_supplicant
;;
*)
;;
esac
exit $?
```

**cat /etc/pm/config.d/config**

```
SUSPEND_MODULES="ath10k_pci"
```

**Error log after resume:**

```
 ath10k_pci 0000:04:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
[   52.941724] ath10k_pci 0000:04:00.0: failed to wake target for write32 of 0x00000000 at 0x00034400: -110
[   52.952859] ath10k_pci 0000:04:00.0: failed to wake target for write32 of 0x00000000 at 0x00034404: -110
[   52.963313] ath10k_pci 0000:04:00.0: failed to wake target for read32 at 0x00034410: -110
[   52.973762] ath10k_pci 0000:04:00.0: failed to wake target for write32 of 0xffff0000 at 0x00034410: -110
[   52.984213] ath10k_pci 0000:04:00.0: failed to wake target for read32 at 0x0003444c: -110
[   52.994663] ath10k_pci 0000:04:00.0: failed to wake target for write32 of 0xffff0000 at 0x0003444c: -110
[   53.005114] ath10k_pci 0000:04:00.0: failed to wake target for write32 of 0x00000000 at 0x00034408: -110
[   53.015563] ath10k_pci 0000:04:00.0: failed to wake target for write32 of 0x00000000 at 0x0003440c: -110
[   53.026037] ath10k_pci 0000:04:00.0: failed to wake target for read32 at 0x00034450: -110
[   53.036495] ath10k_pci 0000:04:00.0: failed to wake target for write32 of 0xffff0000 at 0x00034450: -110
[   54.332051] ath10k_pci 0000:04:00.0: pci irq legacy interrupts 0 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[   57.467798] ath10k_pci 0000:04:00.0: failed to read device register, device is gone
[   57.467809] ath10k_pci 0000:04:00.0: failed to reset chip: -5
[   57.478781] ath10k_pci: probe of 0000:04:00.0 failed with error -5
```

**uname -a**

> Linux sahal 4.4.0-18-generic #34~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 7 18:31:54
>   UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I really need help now . Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I used [Owais Lone](https://askubuntu.com/users/214/owais-lone)'s [answer to a similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452826/wireless-networking-not-working-after-resume-in-ubuntu-14-04/608897#608897) to enable automatic resume of wifi after suspension for my laptop (a Dell Precision) on 16.04 LTS.

Like Owais, I created /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_resume_wifi:

```
#!/bin/sh

case "${1}" in
    resume|thaw)
      nmcli radio wifi off && nmcli radio wifi on;;
esac
```

followed by a `sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_resume_wifi`.

In case you're wondering about the double semicolons or the solitary close parenthesis like I was, see http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_03.html -- that's just how the case syntax works.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution finally! Just make this script to remove the module before suspend and reload after.

https://pastebin.com/93pAZC45