# wiFi detection problems after installing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: wireless

I had installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and having trouble detecting Wifi connection . Please Help..Any suggestions ?

I did ipconfig /release after logging in my windows 10. Doesn't seem to help. 
How do I debug this ?

Comment: Could be the same problem as this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/760075/cant-view-wifi-networks-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-16-04
Try disabling Secure Boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow the same issue. My wifi adapter is not detected within graphical session.

However, such a command succeed :

```
$ sudo iw dev wlp1s0 scan
```

Looks like it may be possible to connect using command line... :-|