# Ubuntu LTS 16, WiFi doesn't work

Tags: wireless, connection

I currently switched to Ubuntu OS after having Windows for such a long time. The WiFi was not working on the windows OS either, I thought that perhaps switching could help. Unfortunately, I can only use a wired connection on this laptop.

I believe that it is an HP envy dv6 7124nr

Output of `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 650M] (rev a1)
08:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
0a:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 07)
```

Output of `lsmod`:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
uvcvideo               90112  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_core         36864  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_v4l2
videodev              176128  4 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1
snd_hda_codec_idt      57344  1
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  1 snd_hda_codec_idt
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
snd_hda_intel          36864  3
coretemp               16384  0
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_core           73728  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
kvm                   536576  0
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
hp_wmi                 16384  0
rtsx_pci_ms            20480  0
snd_pcm               106496  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
memstick               20480  1 rtsx_pci_ms
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    81920  17 snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
aesni_intel           167936  0
joydev                 20480  0
input_leds             16384  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
hp_accel               28672  0
hp_wireless            16384  0
intel_smartconnect     16384  0
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
shpchp                 36864  0
lpc_ich                24576  0
serio_raw              16384  0
mei_me                 36864  0
mei                    98304  1 mei_me
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
lis3lv02d              20480  1 hp_accel
input_polldev          16384  1 lis3lv02d
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
mac_hid                16384  0
cryptd                 20480  2 aesni_intel,ablk_helper
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                40960  2
nouveau              1495040  1
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         24576  0
i915                 1208320  3
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
ttm                    98304  1 nouveau
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 i915,nouveau
drm_kms_helper        139264  2 i915,nouveau
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
psmouse               126976  0
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
ahci                   36864  3
drm                   360448  8 ttm,i915,drm_kms_helper,nouveau
r8169                  81920  0
libahci                32768  1 ahci
mii                    16384  1 r8169
rtsx_pci               53248  2 rtsx_pci_ms,rtsx_pci_sdmmc
wmi                    20480  3 hp_wmi,mxm_wmi,nouveau
video                  40960  2 i915,nouveau
fjes                   28672  0
```

No output from `rfkill list all`.

Output of `dmesg|grep wl`:

```
[    0.000000] DMI: Hewlett-Packard HP ENVY dv6 Notebook PC/181E, BIOS F.2D 08/04/2014
```

Comment: Please open terminal and provide in your question  output of following commands: lspci, lsmod, rfkill list all, dmesg|grep wl.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't view Wifi networks after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/760075/cant-view-wifi-networks-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: I supose that you have checked your wireless network with other devices and it worked, is that correct?

Comment: @migrc, yes everything with wifi capabilities works fine, it's just this laptop giving me problems. I had this issue before I even installed Ubuntu.

Comment: @kukulo done, dont think im missing anything

Comment: Do you have the wifi hardware enabled. I cannot see the wifi card in the lspci command. I see only the ethernet controller, which is cable connection. Enable the wifi in BIOS/UEFI or hardware switch and post the output of the lspci command again. This time more in an ordered manner. Use the code prefix when pasting output from terminal - I think it is four spaces in the beginning of the each line.

Comment: @kukulo might sound a bit like a noob, but how can i access the BIOS on ubuntu?

Comment: @kukulo i found it and apparently there is a "!" mark next to the network settings thing in the boot order

Comment: I guess this is a hardware issue. Could you enable the hw switch or BIOS?

Comment: i enabled the network adapter to get rid of the "!" but nothing happened in terms of the wifi working

Comment: Can you please post the output of lspci command again?

Comment: @kukulo I get the same exact thing

Comment: I do not see the wifi card in your output of lspci. Is the hardware switch/bios enabled?