# Wi-Fi problem with Ubuntu 16.04 on Lenovo G50—45

Tags: wireless, network-manager

I clean installed Ubuntu 16.04 today. All seems to be working fine except Wi-Fi. The drop down menu shows no Wi-Fi connection option.

1. I did a rfkill list -

Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no

2. Then tried lshw -class network -

*-network 
Description: Network controller 
Product: QCA6164 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
Vebdor: Qualcomm Atheros
Physical id: 0
Bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
Version: 20
Width: 64 bits
Clock: 33 MHz
Capabilities: bus_master cap_list
Configuration: driver=ath10k_pci latency=0
Resources: irq:39 memory:f0800000-f09fffff

3. Tried almost every solution provided here - [Can't view Wifi networks after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760075/cant-view-wifi-networks-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-16-04)

I think somehow either Ubuntu is not detecting my Wi-Fi hardware or I don't have the sufficient driver to get it working. Please help me.

N.B. - Since my laptop has no internet connection, I had to type every details through my phone. So any mistake is regretted.

Answer (score 1):

Please download this file on some other computer and transfer it on a USB key or similar: http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.158_all.deb

Drag and drop it to the desktop of your Lenovo. Open a terminal and do:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware*.deb
```

Reboot and let us know if it is now working.