# My wireless (BCM43142) won't work

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, broadcom

14.04 was getting along with the wireless card until today and I tried many things to fix it but got myself into a mess where I felt reinstalling completely was the best option. I installed 16.04 instead. The original problem is still there D: The problem appears similar to the one asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760075/cant-view-wifi-networks-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-16-04) in many respects, except that restarting Network Manager has no effect and the output of iwconfig shows no wireless extensions.

```
lspci -nn
```

output includes

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM34132 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
```

Secure boot is off and bcmwl-kernel-source is the latest version. I purged, updated and reinstalled it, to be sure.

```
sudo rfkill list
```

shows no wifi devices, only bluetooth. What's my next step, here?

Comment: If it was working before and stopped working for no apparent reason could it just be a hardware failure?

Comment: Try a live session w/ 14.04.1 and see if works. If not, you know it's a hardware issue; if so, then there's something about the 4.4 kernel that's the problem.

Comment: so what I actually ended up doing when I was reminded that it could be a hardware thing was remembering that I had a USB wireless card and hooking that up and now it works fine. I might try booting from a disk of an older version at some point too, just to check, especially if the dongle doesn't perform as well as the onboard card did. But it seems likely that the onboard is dead. I will let you know how it goes if I try it.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Network` and `iwconfig`? That would provide a little more info as to the state of the device driver (a kernel upgrade likely broke it or something). Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: @qwanderer Please pay attention to the Secure Boot issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r` dkms build-essential bcmwl-kernel-source
```