# W-lan not found on Lenovo

Tags: lenovo

I work with a Lenovo B580 and Ubuntu 16.04. My device doesn't find W-Lan anymore (used to up until 2 weeks ago). I use this wlan device and drivers. Any suggestions for help?

[image]

Comment: So it suddenly stopped working?

Comment: What is the exact response from the terminal command: `sudo modprobe wl` Required key, maybe??

Comment: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Required key not available

What now?

Comment: Android Dev, yes it suddenly stopped.

Comment: Ok, thanks gyus. This one worked and fixed the issue. 

http://askubuntu.com/questions/760075/cant-view-wifi-networks-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-16-04

Thank you very much for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try checking the blacklist.conf file in the folder /etc/modprobe.d ??
Sometimes my wifi seems useless on various computers/ubuntu versions. 
Usually putting a # in front of the next ones solves the problem for me.

blacklist eth1394
blacklist bcm43xx

( Yes, you need to ben root to do this of course :-)

Comment: Thanks Martijn, unfortunately it didn't work for me.