# Wifi does not find any hotspots after updating to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, wireless, secure-boot

I've installed Ubuntu on my laptop (Lenovo Yoga 13) recently and Wifi worked. Then I've upgraded from 15 to 16 and wifi seems to work, but just not finding anything anymore.

Regarding to this question [Can't view Wifi networks after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760075/cant-view-wifi-networks-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-16-04) I've figured out that it has something to do with secure boot.

I've disabled it in bios and everytime I do this, it works for a while... but at any point (reboots and sometimes it just stopped working, I've got the suspicion that it's time limited) it will fail again. None of the answeres there helped me to keep wifi working permanently.

How can I make this persistent?
Thanks in advance.