# Wifi not working after 16.04 upgrade

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 16.04, broadcom

I have an [Asus 1015E-DS02](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00COZRNX6)

I've tried the solutions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760075/cant-view-wifi-networks-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-16-04) to no avail.

I've also tried the solutions on [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761180/wifi-doesnt-work-after-suspend-after-16-04-upgrade) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762198/16-04-lts-wifi-connection-issues) even though my wifi hasn't worked at all since the upgrade.

I'd also like to note that I upgraded to 16.04 almost immediately after upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04. I'm almost certain that Wi-Fi did work at 14.04.

[image]
[image]

Is there any significance to it saying that "This device is using an **alterate** driver?

Here's the results of [this all in one script](https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/309547).

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 24 Sep 2016 18:59 PDT -0700

Booted last: 24 Sep 2016 00:00 PDT -0700

Script from: 08 Jul 2016 02:16 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.2.0-98-generic #138-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 11 12:33:01 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: AzureWave BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:2047]
    Kernel modules: brcmsmac, bcma

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8162 Fast Ethernet [1969:1090] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. AR8162 Fast Ethernet [1043:115d]
    Kernel driver in use: alx

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:5188 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

asus_nb_wmi            16990  0
asus_wmi               24392  1 asus_nb_wmi
wmi                    19256  1 asus_wmi
sparse_keymap          13890  1 asus_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth1' [IF1]>  
          inet addr:192.168.1.74  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'eth1' [IF1]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5727 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2826 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:3
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1179744 (1.1 MB)  TX bytes:459222 (459.2 KB)
          Interrupt:19 

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'virbr0' [IF2]>  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:665 (665.0 B)

virbr0-nic Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'virbr0' [IF2]>  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

virbr0    no wireless extensions.

eth1      no wireless extensions.

virbr0-nic  no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth1

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search attlocal.net

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root     10628     1  0 18:26 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eth1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Qualcomm Atheros
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        AR8162 Fast Ethernet
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         alx
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               alx
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'eth1' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:03:00.0/net/eth1
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       eth1
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       d39a1836-67cf-41f3-b0e5-25a057eecef1
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{15}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   d39a1836-67cf-41f3-b0e5-25a057eecef1 | Wired connection 1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.74/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.254
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.254
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          attlocal.net
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       next_server = 192.168.1.254
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       expiry = 1474853452
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       routers = 192.168.1.254
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       ip_address = 192.168.1.74
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       domain_name = attlocal.net
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 43200
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.1.255
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       domain_name_servers = 192.168.1.254
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       dhcp_rebinding_time = 75600
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       network_number = 192.168.1.0
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.254
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         2602:306:b803:4bf0::3ec/128
IP6.ADDRESS[2]:                         2602:306:b803:4bf0:459d:2089:bd3e:a69e/128
IP6.ADDRESS[3]:                         fe80::<IP6 'eth1' [IF1]>/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            fe80::62fe:20ff:fe51:413d
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 2602:306:b803:4bf0::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = fe80::62fe:20ff:fe51:413d/128, nh = ::, mt = 100
IP6.DNS[1]:                             2602:306:b803:4bf0::1
DHCP6.OPTION[1]:                        dhcp6_client_id = 0:1:0:1:1d:31:a8:25:dc:85:de:27:ef:cd
DHCP6.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp6_name_servers = 2602:306:b803:4bf0::1
DHCP6.OPTION[3]:                        requested_dhcp6_name_servers = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[4]:                        rebind = 5760
DHCP6.OPTION[5]:                        max_life = 7500
DHCP6.OPTION[6]:                        preferred_life = 7200
DHCP6.OPTION[7]:                        requested_dhcp6_domain_search = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[8]:                        requested_dhcp6_client_id = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[9]:                        life_starts = 1474767064
DHCP6.OPTION[10]:                       ip6_address = 2602:306:b803:4bf0::3ec
DHCP6.OPTION[11]:                       ip6_prefixlen = 64
DHCP6.OPTION[12]:                       renew = 3600
DHCP6.OPTION[13]:                       starts = 1474767064
DHCP6.OPTION[14]:                       iaid = "+LEa"
DHCP6.OPTION[15]:                       dhcp6_server_id = 0:3:0:1:<MAC address>

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         virbr0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           bridge
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceBridge
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         bridge
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'virbr0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /virtual/device/placeholder/0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       virbr0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    yes
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     no
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               yes
BRIDGE.SLAVES:                          
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.122.1/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         virbr0-nic
GENERAL.TYPE:                           tun
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceTun
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         tun
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 1.6
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'virbr0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /virtual/device/placeholder/3
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       virbr0-nic
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    yes
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     no
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               yes
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/#SFO FREE WIFI]] (600 root)
[connection] id=#SFO FREE WIFI | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=#SFO FREE WIFI | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Verizon-SM-N915V-3D94]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Verizon-SM-N915V-3D94 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Verizon-SM-N915V-3D94 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/SCH-I6058B4B]] (600 root)
[connection] id=SCH-I6058B4B | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=SCH-I6058B4B | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/KaiserGuest]] (600 root)
[connection] id=KaiserGuest | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=KaiserGuest | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/BW - Encina]] (600 root)
[connection] id=BW - Encina | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=BW - Encina | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/GuestANR]] (600 root)
[connection] id=GuestANR | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=GuestANR | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ATT4074 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=ATT4074 1 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=ATT4074 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/HOME-EF6E-2.4]] (600 root)
[connection] id=HOME-EF6E-2.4 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=HOME-EF6E-2.4 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Verizon VS985 4G DA29]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Verizon VS985 4G DA29 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Verizon VS985 4G DA29 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/HTC6535LVW f7 70]] (600 root)
[connection] id=HTC6535LVW f7 70 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=HTC6535LVW f7 70 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ATT640]] (600 root)
[connection] id=ATT640 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=ATT640 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/DEADPOOL ECO1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=DEADPOOL ECO1 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=DEADPOOL ECO1 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/SCH-I5352986]] (600 root)
[connection] id=SCH-I5352986 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=SCH-I5352986 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ATT4074]] (600 root)
[connection] id=ATT4074 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=ATT4074 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/BWPacificGrove]] (600 root)
[connection] id=BWPacificGrove | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=BWPacificGrove | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

nl80211 not found.

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

virbr0    no frequency information.

eth1      no frequency information.

virbr0-nic  no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

virbr0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth1      Interface doesn't support scanning.

virbr0-nic  Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

##### module parameters #################

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
asus-wmi
asus-nb-wmi
lp
lp

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/oss-compat.conf]
install snd-pcm modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { modprobe --quiet snd-pcm-oss ; : ; }
install snd-mixer modprobe --ignore-install snd-mixer $CMDLINE_OPTS && { modprobe --quiet snd-mixer-oss ; : ; }
install snd-seq modprobe --ignore-install snd-seq $CMDLINE_OPTS && { modprobe --quiet snd-seq-midi ; modprobe --quiet snd-seq-oss ; : ; }

[/etc/modprobe.d/osspd.conf]
blacklist snd-pcm-oss
blacklist snd-mixer-oss
blacklist snd-seq-oss

[/etc/modprobe.d/qemu-system-x86.conf]
options kvm_intel nested=1

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

[/etc/pm/sleep.d/11_usb_s3] (755 root)
case "${1}" in
        suspend | hibernate)
                for i in `lspci -vv | grep "USB controller" | awk '/EHCI/ {print $1}'`
                do
                   echo "0000:$i" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci_hcd/unbind
                done
                ;;
        resume | thaw)
                for i in `lspci -vv | grep "USB controller" | awk '/EHCI/ {print $1}'`
                do
                   echo "0000:$i" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci_hcd/bind
                done
                ;;
esac

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:04:00.2 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x168c:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:03:00.0 (ath9k)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"
# PCI device 0x14e4:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:02:00.0 (brcmsmac)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan1"
# PCI device 0x1969:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:03:00.0 (alx)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth1' [IF1]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"

##### dmesg #############################

[   20.645767] Qualcomm Atheros(R) AR813x/AR815x/AR816x PCI-E Ethernet Network Driver
[   20.758199] alx: Atheros Gigabit Network Connection
[   21.046947] psmouse serio4: elantech: assuming hardware version 4 (with firmware version 0x361f03)
[   31.601528] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
[   34.422405] device virbr0-nic entered promiscuous mode
[   34.891842] virbr0: topology change detected, propagating
[   34.891851] virbr0: port 1(virbr0-nic) entering forwarding state (repeated 3 times)
[   35.317521] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): virbr0-nic: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[  113.339703] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready (repeated 3 times)
[  217.524593] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth1: link becomes ready
[  327.371436] alx 0000:03:00.0: eth1: speed = 0x2f, autoneg = 1
[  377.261051] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready (repeated 6 times)
[  672.698687] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth1: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

**EDIT:** After following [this forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=181914) I've noticed that
`lspci -vnn -d 14e4:` gives `Capabilities: <access denied>`. When looking for `/var/lib/dkms/broadcom-wl/` as suggested, it did not exist. I don't know what that means but it feels important maybe.

**EDIT:** The solutions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) did not work either.

**EDIT:** A friend of mine took a look at it and thinks that it might be related to a problem with the UEFI.

Comment: Perhaps it's buried in your log files some place but in  your first sentence could please state your computer make and model and wifi card make and model if you know it?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Done, thanks. Is the Wi-Fi card model what shows up in the second picture?

Comment: your second screen snapshot is blurry on my screen and I can't make our your model number, perhaps to my bad vision. I did notice "STA" in there and people were writing about that last night in AskUbuntu so you might want to search on that for answers.

Comment: I'm not sure the drivers *brcmsmac, bcma* are correct. There were many changes since 12.04. Why would someone install and upgrade12.04 > 14.04 > 16.04 instead of installing 16.04 from scratch. How does it work in a 16.04 live session?

Comment: The drivers are correct after all. Read  https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2214110 , scroll down to Special Case #1 and try that. Again, if it works in a live session - it should - go ahead and install from scratch.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Special Case #1 didn't work

Comment: @ Third time hopefully the charm: * if it works in a live session - it should - go ahead and install from scratch.*

Comment: it looks like a network manager issue. did you open the `/etc/network/interfaces` file and check? see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager#Issues

Comment: A big issue is the kernel.  It is from Ubuntu 12.04.  Have you rebooted since?  Installed updates?

Comment: @Jeremy31 Yes, several times

Comment: Is there another linux distro on the hard drive and edit to include results for `ls /lib/modules`

Comment: You have a wrong kernel and a wrong driver.

Comment: @Jeremy31 No, ubuntu is the only OS on the laptop

Comment: @Pilot6 What would I do to fix that?

Comment: First fix the kernel by `sudo apt install linux-generic`. Everything else may start working.

Comment: Don't forget to reboot into the new kernel after installing it. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to install the correct kernel by

```
sudo apt install linux-generic
```

Then remove the wrong driver by

```
sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

After a reboot everything should work.

Comment: Very good catch! I didn't look at the kernel version at all.