# ubuntu 16.04 how to RE-enable wifi

Tags: wireless, 16.04

There used to be a option "enable wifi" on the top-bar. However, I un-click that option and that option never pops out again. How can I RE-enable my wifi. Thanks a lot.

I have try `rfkill list all` in the command line. It shows both hardware and software unblock no.

And I tried <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. Still didn't work.

Comment: Check this page. http://askubuntu.com/questions/760075/cant-view-wifi-networks-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: it's kind of weird that I can't even find Broadcom in my software manager. :(

Answer (score 6):

I tried `nmcli radio wifi off` and then `nmcli radio wifi on` and restart the computer. Then, it somehow works!

Comment: Same problem with old computer running Bodhi Linux (Ubuntu 16.04) and these commands resolved the issue, thanks.