# Wifi not working on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: networking, 16.04, wireless, broadcom

First off, let me start by saying that I am well aware that many other people have asked similar questions, and have had their questions answered and their problems solved. I am here because I have attempted a range of the solutions already posted, and none of them have worked.

Some background: I am running Ubuntu 16.04 off of a flash drive. The WiFi does not work. But, it's not just that I try to connect to a network, and it doesn't connect; rather, the idea of WiFi itself seems to be a foreign concept to the system. Nowhere is there any option to even see available WiFi networks. Clicking on the network icon yields: (parentheses indicate grayed-out):

```
(Ethernet network)
(disconnected)
VPN Connections→
Enable Networking – this is checked
(Connection information)
Edit connections
```

If I run `service network-manager restart`, which some guides say will fix the wifi menu, I get a notification that I am now disconnected, and more options become grayed out. I've also tried typing `nm-applet` in terminal and that did nothing.

One post suggested running `sudo ifconfig wlp4s0 up`. This did nothing, and gave the message: `wlp4s0: ERROR while getting interface flags: no such device`.

Running `sudo modprobe -wl` yields: `Error: Could not insert wl: required key not available`. Researching that, it seems that the error comes from having secure boot enabled. So I go into the BIOS, disable secure boot, and then run the command again, and get the same result.

After disabling secure boot, I then tried running `sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source` then `sudo apt-get install linux-generic bcmwl-kernel-source`, rebooted, and there was no effect.

My wifi card is Broadcom BCM4312 802.11b/g/n and my PCI Id is 14e4:4365 (rev 01). This information in hand, I followed the instructions of another post, which suggested I go to `/etc/pm/config` and edit `config.d`, adding `SUSPEND_MODULES="BCM4312"`. There was no `config.d` file in that directory, and I was told I did not have permission to save a file there, which makes no sense because I am the only user.

I've gone into Settings > Software and Updates, and enable the Broadcom wifi card.

Output of `iwconfig`:

```
lo    no wireless extensions
enp14s0   no wireless extensions
```

I'm not sure what that means.

I've tried all the steps at the following posts:

- [Can't view Wifi networks after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760075/cant-view-wifi-networks-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-16-04)
- [16.04 LTS wifi connection issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762198/16-04-lts-wifi-connection-issues)
- https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/4je63z/no_wireless_on_ubuntu_1604/Q
- [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

And non of them seem to work. I am not sure where to go from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The "no wireless extensions" message means the device isn't a *wireless* network device (lo is the loopback interface, and I'm assuming enp14s0 is a wired interface of sorts).  For some reason the device isn't being given an interface in the system, possibly due to driver failure. Can you post dmesg output please?

Comment: The output of `dmesg` is over 25 pages- it's too long to post here. Anything specific you're looking for?

Comment: Just a comprehensive detailed log of all PCI bridges, devices, wireless networking, and driver (and any more of its dependencies) possibly failing.  I don't think it's a problem to post 25 pages here, it goes into a scrollable box, but if there's anything you specifically don't want to share (avant-garde h/w), then by all means trim away. One can also post places like pastebin if necessary, just not sure how long they'll last there vs. this askubuntu entry.

Comment: Please do: `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`. After it finishes, reboot and run these commands and show us the results: `sudo modprobe wl` (not -wl) and also: `rfkill list all` Welcome to AskUbuntu.