# Networkmanager does not know that I am online, after resuming from hibernate

Tags: wireless, gnome, network-manager, hibernate, evolution

The following question is very close to this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452826/wireless-networking-not-working-after-resume-in-ubuntu-14-04). When closing the lid of my notebook or going to hybernate and waking up my Ubuntu Mate 16.04 machine, the nm-applet shows, that I am offline.

Different from the linked question above, I am not offline, I am online, but it just shows that I am offline.

Restarting the network-manager service helped sometimes.

Anyways currently this does not seem to have an effect anymore. It is annoying because some applications like evolution appear to share the same source for determining the online status than the nm-applet. That means, that in this state I can not check my e-mails but browse the web.

How can I ensure that after waking up the machine from hibernate the wireless network connection is established well and identified as established?

Comment: I think your issue is similar than the one I had.
This answer fixed my problem:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/761180/wifi-doesnt-work-after-suspend-after-16-04-upgrade
Try it and good luck!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wifi doesn't work after suspend after 16.04 upgrade](http://askubuntu.com/questions/761180/wifi-doesnt-work-after-suspend-after-16-04-upgrade)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had wicd and Networkmanager installed. Uninstalling wicd, together with implementing the solutions from the above linked question, solved my problem.

It seems as if both wicd and the network managing routines of gnome try to connect to my wifi when I am disconnected. The wicd routines are usually quicker and than the gnome ones do not recognize that I am online, which leads to confusion in other programs, like evolution.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not 100% convinced this is a 16.04 issue as this has recently resurfaced for me on **14.04.4**. For me `sudo nmcli nm sleep false` wakes up network manager.

I know I’ve had this problem before as I had a script with the above command, but I can’t remember if I found a solution or it was just fixed somewhere along the way.

Comment: nm is unknown, when I run the command

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? This works for me in 14.04.

One of the other posts I looked at was [Wireless networking not working after resume in Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/452826/wireless-networking-not-working-after-resume-in-ubuntu-14-04). Someone there was using `nmcli r wifi off && nmcli r wifi on` in 14.10, but I’ve not idea what ‘`r`’ is. `nm` is Network Manager.

Comment: Maybe that I am using Ubuntu Mate on Version 16.04 contributes to the issue. Mate Network-Monitor knows that I am online, but nm-applet not. Unfortunately Evolution does not know it either!