# Wifi connectivity problem in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, wireless

Wifi is working properly on my laptop (hp-ab220tx) but when I suspend or close the laptop when it is working, now when I open it there I will lose the wifi connection. To get back the wifi connection all I need to do is restart the laptop.

Here are the network details:

```
description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: 70:77:81:bf:f9:1b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=4.2.0-42-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.123 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:18 ioport:5000(size=256) memory:c6100000-c6103fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 0a
       serial: 3c:a8:2a:bc:2c:2d
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8107e-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.1.22 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:49 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:c6004000-c6004fff memory:c6000000-c6003fff
```

Comment: Is this the same issue as asked here?http://askubuntu.com/questions/452826/wireless-networking-not-working-after-resume-in-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 0):

Have you turned the WiFi device off and then back on? This is often faster than a full reboot. There is usually a WiFi switch or button on HP Laptops. Use it to turn the WiFi off, then back on. This should restore its function (but is of course only a temporary solution). Also, could you provide us a more specific model number? HP shows no results on their website for an ab200tx, AB200tx, AB200Tx or AB200TX. Your model number is on the sticker at the bottom of your laptop, near the serial number and is usually labeled "p/n".