# Wireless network does not resume after sleep on 16.04 LTS

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 16.04, iwlwifi

I've been having a problem with the wireless network not reconnecting after sleep for the last few versions of Ubuntu, with the latest being 16.04 LTS.

Here are the laptop specifications:

- Lenovo Thinkpad X230 Tablet (often X230t)
- Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS 64-bit
- Intel® Core™ i5-3320M CPU @ 2.60GHz × 4
- Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] (rev 34)
- Default Ubuntu wireless driver (iwlwifi)

Additional details from modinfo:

```
$ modinfo iwlwifi | grep -v 'pci:' | grep -v 'iwlwifi-'
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-34-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
srcversion:     651BF6CBF283F6F817B8F3A
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           d0i3_disable:disable d0i3 functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           lar_disable:disable LAR functionality (default: N) (bool)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)
```

Let me know if you need any more specs.

To replicate the issue:

1. Turn on or reboot laptop.
2. Put laptop to sleep
3. After a few minutes, turn laptop back on
4. No wireless connection is possible

I have tried the solutions outlined on this page, but they do not work consistently.

[Wireless networking not working after resume in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452826/wireless-networking-not-working-after-resume-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Specifically I have this modification applied:

```
$ cat /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_resume_wifi 
#!/bin/sh

case "${1}" in
  resume|thaw)
    nmcli radio wifi off && nmcli radio wifi on;
esac
```

It works probably half of the time. Since the prior post is specific to Ubuntu 14.04, many things have probably changed since solutions were suggested that invalidate those solutions.

Comment: There is no reliable solution of this bug yet.

Comment: Does this help? `sudo service network-manager restart`  ?

Comment: No, restarting network-manager does not work consistently, either