# Can no longer connect to some WiFis

Tags: 14.04, networking, kubuntu, network-manager

My problem is, that I can not connect to some WiFis while others still work. Everything worked fine a week ago. The mobile hotspot created by my phone is still working fine.

This problem is more prevalent since I frequently send my notebook to sleep, instead of shutting down. I have checked the question [Wireless networking not working after resume in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452826/wireless-networking-not-working-after-resume-in-ubuntu-14-04), but this did not help.

I would be grateful for any help with this, including pointers which logs etc. could provide more insight.

That said, sorry for the vague title, please feel free to edit for clarification.

### What exactly happens

1. I (re)start.
2. Network manager icon shows a connected WiFi.
3. In rapid succession the following notifications are shown:

   - **my wifi**: Connection **my wifi** deactivated
   - Wireless Interface (wlan0):  No secrets were provided
4. The connection drops, network manager shows the "searching", then the "connecting" icon.
5. Several retries (~3) take place. Each shows the following two notifications:

   - **my wifi**: Connection **my wifi** deactivated
   - Wireless Interface (wlan0): IP configuration was unavailable.
6. After the retries, network manager shows a question mark and gives up.

### Hardware:

Lenovo Thinkpad T540p

```
$ sudo lshw -c network
    *-network
           description: Wireless interface
           product: Wireless 7260
           vendor: Intel Corporation
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
           logical name: wlan0
           version: bb
           serial: 5c:c5:d4:e0:1c:94
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
           configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.16.0-52-generic firmware=25.228.9.0 ip=192.168.43.77 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
           resources: irq:47 memory:f2800000-f2801fff
    ...
```

### Logs

Excerpt from `dmesg` which shows deconnecting from a working wifi, connecting to , failing and reconnecting to the working one.

```
[ 1916.725149] wlan0: deauthenticating from 80:37:73:da:06:c0 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 1916.740742] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 1916.743159] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 1916.743162] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[ 1916.743163] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[ 1916.743166] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1916.743169] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1916.743171] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1916.743172] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1916.743173] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1916.743184] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: DE
[ 1916.744992] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: DE
[ 1916.744994] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[ 1916.744995] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[ 1916.744997] cfg80211:   (2400000 KHz - 2483500 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1916.744998] cfg80211:   (5150000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1916.744999] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5350000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[ 1916.745000] cfg80211:   (5470000 KHz - 5725000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2698 mBm), (0 s)
[ 1916.745002] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 65880000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1919.554137] wlan0: authenticate with 80:37:73:da:06:c0
[ 1919.556786] wlan0: send auth to 80:37:73:da:06:c0 (try 1/3)
[ 1919.558598] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1919.562481] wlan0: associate with 80:37:73:da:06:c0 (try 1/3)
[ 1919.566024] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 80:37:73:da:06:c0 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[ 1919.567199] wlan0: associated
[ 1921.188286] wlan0: deauthenticating from 80:37:73:da:06:c0 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 1921.191810] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 1921.196341] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 1921.196343] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[ 1921.196345] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[ 1921.196347] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1921.196348] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1921.196349] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1921.196350] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1921.196351] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1921.196500] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: DE
[ 1921.198385] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: DE
[ 1921.198388] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[ 1921.198388] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[ 1921.198390] cfg80211:   (2400000 KHz - 2483500 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1921.198391] cfg80211:   (5150000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1921.198392] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5350000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[ 1921.198393] cfg80211:   (5470000 KHz - 5725000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2698 mBm), (0 s)
[ 1921.198394] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 65880000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1924.652612] wlan0: authenticate with 02:1a:11:fb:34:fc
[ 1924.655299] wlan0: send auth to 02:1a:11:fb:34:fc (try 1/3)
[ 1924.657106] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1924.660085] wlan0: associate with 02:1a:11:fb:34:fc (try 1/3)
[ 1924.667085] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 02:1a:11:fb:34:fc (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[ 1924.667930] wlan0: associated
[ 1924.667980] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: DE
[ 1924.669881] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: DE
[ 1924.669884] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[ 1924.669885] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[ 1924.669887] cfg80211:   (2400000 KHz - 2483500 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1924.669888] cfg80211:   (5150000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1924.669890] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5350000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[ 1924.669891] cfg80211:   (5470000 KHz - 5725000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2698 mBm), (0 s)
[ 1924.669892] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 65880000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1924.687721] wlan0: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by 02:1a:11:fb:34:fc
[ 1924.700790] wlan0: deauthenticating from 02:1a:11:fb:34:fc by local choice (Reason: 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID)
[ 1924.710385] wlan0: authenticate with 02:1a:11:fb:34:fc
[ 1924.712791] wlan0: send auth to 02:1a:11:fb:34:fc (try 1/3)
[ 1924.713015] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 1924.714585] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1924.714660] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 1924.714663] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[ 1924.714665] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[ 1924.714667] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1924.714668] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1924.714669] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1924.714670] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1924.714672] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1924.714680] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: DE
[ 1924.716136] wlan0: associate with 02:1a:11:fb:34:fc (try 1/3)
[ 1924.716148] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: DE
[ 1924.716150] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[ 1924.716151] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[ 1924.716152] cfg80211:   (2400000 KHz - 2483500 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1924.716153] cfg80211:   (5150000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1924.716155] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5350000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[ 1924.716155] cfg80211:   (5470000 KHz - 5725000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2698 mBm), (0 s)
[ 1924.716156] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 65880000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1924.723515] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 02:1a:11:fb:34:fc (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[ 1924.724258] wlan0: associated
[ 1924.724293] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: DE
[ 1924.725783] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: DE
[ 1924.725786] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[ 1924.725787] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[ 1924.725789] cfg80211:   (2400000 KHz - 2483500 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1924.725790] cfg80211:   (5150000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1924.725792] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5350000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[ 1924.725793] cfg80211:   (5470000 KHz - 5725000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2698 mBm), (0 s)
[ 1924.725794] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 65880000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1924.793764] wlan0: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by 02:1a:11:fb:34:fc
```

Comment: I seem to have the same issue sometimes... It will just show the "Disconnected from wireless" icon in the notifications bar.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While this answer might not be terribly helpful, maybe it provides some closure.

I never found a solution for this problem other than "restarting until I works again". However, after an update to 16.04 the error did not (yet) turn up again and everything runs smoothly. So updating to a newer version solved this for me.

Comment: Same problem here, restarting is not a solution.