# After awakening, wireless network is not found

Tags: 16.04, wireless, network-manager, suspend

Often, when my laptop goes to suspension and then awakenes, it does not find the wifi network I am usually connected to (eduroam). When I open the network menu, I see "V" both near "Enable networking" and near "Enable wifi", and I also see one wifi network that I cannot connect to since it is locked, but I do not see eduroam. I can fix this by restarting the network manager, like this:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

But, it is annoying to do this each time after awakening. How can I prevent Ubuntu from forgetting my wifi network?

Comment: Read `man pm-action`. Some script in there is (or can be) responsible for restarting your connection.

Comment: Suspend your computer, and if the wifi isn't working, run `nmcli g` and [edit] your question with it. Check this though http://askubuntu.com/questions/452826/wireless-networking-not-working-after-resume-in-ubuntu-14-04?rq=1